# asp.net Knockoutjs Async call to JS library before submitting

Tags: jquery, asp.net, knockout.js

I am using Knockoutjs in old asp.net webapplication. I have requirement that on asp.net submit button click, I must call as JS library async and get response and then post the asp.net submit
(i.e initiate asp.net button click event)?

Is there a way in Knockoutjs to wait for response from Async call and then submit? problem I have is since asp.net is sync and I when I make async call to 
JS library the form is submitting even before I receive response from JS library.

```
self.onButtonClick = function () {

    var jsdatatosubmit = {
        param1: '123',
        param2: '123qwewe'
    };
    object.functionTest(jsdatatosubmit)
    .success(

        function (response) {

            return true; //Submit asp.net form Call submit click event
        }   
    )
    .error();

    return false; //instead of true         

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has 2 parts.

1. prevent submission of form upon clicking button.
2. submit a synchronous request

The code you already have should be sufficient to satisfy 1 (returning false).  You do not need to return true inside of the success callback (in fact, that will never happen since the onButtonClick callback will not wait on the async call to execute before returning).  As far as 2, you can use ko.utils.postJson or a multitude of other libraries that are capable of synchronous posts.

[Here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/) is a blog by the creator of knockout that has some examples.
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/s1sLxemp/6/) is a jsfiddle I did that shows a simple example using it.

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: someProperty">
  <button type="submit" data-bind="click: submit">submit</button>
</form>

var viewModel = {
  someProperty: ko.observable('some text'),
  submit: function(e) {
    ko.utils.postJson('/controller/action', { nameOfActionMethodArgument: this.someProperty });
    return false;
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.querySelector('form'));
```

Comment: do you mind sharing more info about ko.utils.postJson or a multitude of other libraries?? Just don't know how to do that!